# remove one element by name from an array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
collection: {
   _id: ...,
   name: ...,
   elements: [ "aaa", "bbb", "aaa", "aaa", "ccc" ]
}
```

Note that "aaa" occurs several times and that is correct.

I want to remove **one** of the "aaa" elements (I don't care which one). I've tried $pull in various combinations and nothing gives me the result I want (it either pulls other array elements, or all of the "aaa"s.

I need the operation to be atomic, if possible at all.

Comment: Try using distinct method. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: Do you want the "aaa" element to be completely removed, or just omitted in the output? It would be great if you could share the required output structure.

Comment: I want the element to be removed. The result should be that the elements array is either b,a,a,c or a,b,a,c

Comment: @LaxmikantDange - I don't want it distinct. I want to remove **one** of the "aaa", meaning **two** should remain in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to remove one `"aaa"` so that array would be like `["bbb","aaa","aaa","ccc"]` .

I did it like below, there could be another better solution to it, please update if someone has.

PS - i had only 1 element in collection, you can put a condition in update statement.

```
db.getCollection('mydb').updateOne({arrElem:"aaa"},{$set:{"arrElem.$":null}})
db.getCollection('mydb').update({},{$pull:{arrElem:null}})
```

Comment: Thanks. I found this solution already somewhere, but it isn't atomic. I was hoping there is a better solution.